# WordPress and .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, wordpress

I have a website powered by [WordPress MU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPress#Multi-blogging). The front page of the site is translated in several languages. How do I rewrite the following URLs?

```
http://www.example.com/?lang=en
http://www.example.com/?lang=fr
```

to:

```
http://www.example.com/en/
http://www.example.com/fr/
```

This is my current `.htaccess`,

```
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# Uploaded files
RewriteRule ^files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not tested so I am not 100 % sure if it works but that should give you some ideas.

I advice you to take a look at the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html) of mod-rewrite.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$1 [L]

#languages
RewriteRule ^/(en|fr)/(.*)$ /$2?lang=$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
# END WordPress
```

Comment: That's because it says `ReriteRule` instead of `RewriteRule`. Also, these rules will rewrite all `http://example.com/en/` URLs to `http://example.com/?lang=en`.

Comment: Thanks! It's work, but I have been redirected to 404.php instead to index.php. How I can fix that?

Comment: @Vasil: I am not a WP expert but you might have to add index.php to your rule maybe

Answer (score 2):

This will redirect and preserve the original query string:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.+)
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2}) /?lang=$1&%1 [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2}) /?lang=$1 [L]
```

Comment: it's work, but for some reason i get redirect to 404.php instead to index.php :(

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^en  /?lang=en
RewriteRule ^fr  /?lang=fr
```